# How can I program Outlook to send an email in advance and send another if a reply isn't sent?

Tags: vba, outlook

I'd like to program Outlook to send an email in advance, and, if no reply is sent to the target email by x date, send another email.

I've attempted experimentation, dabbling into Excel VBAs, but haven't found a solution.

I'm really quite unsure of how to do this, though I do have programming experience.

Comment: If you are after vba, put this your tags. `#vba` And if possible post your codes to start with.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to program Outlook to send an email in advance

That is a very straightforward task. A lot of samples are available over the internet, for example, sample code in VB.NET:

```
Private Sub CreateSendItem(OutlookApp As Outlook._Application)
    Dim mail As Outlook.MailItem = Nothing
    Dim mailRecipients As Outlook.Recipients = Nothing
    Dim mailRecipient As Outlook.Recipient = Nothing
    Try
        mail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)
        mail.Subject = "A programatically generated e-mail"
        mailRecipients = mail.Recipients
        mailRecipient = mailRecipients.Add("Eugene Astafiev")
        mailRecipient.Resolve()
        If (mailRecipient.Resolved) Then
            mail.Send()
        Else
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(
                "There is no such record in your address book.")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,
            "An exception is occured in the code of add-in.")
    Finally
        If Not IsNothing(mailRecipient) Then Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mailRecipient)
        If Not IsNothing(mailRecipients) Then Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mailRecipients)
        If Not IsNothing(mail) Then Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mail)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Read more about that in the following articles:

- [How To: Create and send an Outlook message programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/02/outlook-create-send-message/)
- [How To: Fill TO,CC and BCC fields in Outlook programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/08/outlook-fill-recipients-programmatically/)
- [How to create and show a new Outlook mail item programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/26/outlook-create-show-message-programmatically/)

> if no reply is sent to the target email by x date, send another email.

You can set the following properties on the email:

- [MailItem.TaskDueDate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.taskduedate?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm1393)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv15)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396) which sets a Date value that represents the due date of the task for this MailItem.
- [MailItem.ReminderSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.reminderset) which sets a Boolean value that is True if a reminder has been set for this item.
- [MailItem.ReminderTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.remindertime) which sets a Date indicating the date and time at which the reminder should occur for the specified item.

In the [Application.Reminder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.reminder?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm431)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv15)%26rd%3Dtrue) event handler you may check whether the mail item was replied or forwarded by reading a low-level property value. The property you would read would be PR_LAST_VERB_EXECUTED (0x10810003). Values are listed below:

```
EXCHIVERB_REPLYTOSENDER = 102
EXCHIVERB_REPLYTOALL = 103
EXCHIVERB_FORWARD = 104
```

Please remember that you can use the `PropertyAccessor` for that:

```
lastVerbExecuted = mailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10810003")
```